# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when running custom unwind segue

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, segue

I'm trying to build an iOS app with this workflow: The user is presented a main view, ViewController in this case, and can then click on an UITableViewCell in order to get directed to DetailCountryViewController through a custom segue (SegueRight with the identifier doneSegueToCountryDetail). This works perfectly. Then, when the user swipes to the right (with a Swipe Gesture Recognizer), it should unwind and send him back to ViewController. Also, with a custom segue, SegueLeft with the identifier segueCountryDetailToMain).
However, this freezes the app (after ViewController is already shown, so this works) and some seconds later it crashes with the code EXC_BAD_ACCESS. Here's my code so far:

**Swift 3**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt
            indexPath: IndexPath){

        let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        let currentCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath!) as UITableViewCell!

        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath!, animated: true)

        titleToPass = currentCell?.textLabel?.text?.capitalized

        if tableView == self.tableViewDone {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "doneSegueToCountryDetail", sender: self)
        } else if tableView == self.tableViewWish {
            performSegue(withIdentifier: "wishSegueToCountryDetail", sender: self)
        }
    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "doneSegueToCountryDetail" || segue.identifier == "wishSegueToCountryDetail" {
            if let exitVC = segue.destination as? DetailCountryViewController {
                exitVC.titleVar = titleToPass
            }
        }
    }

    @IBAction func unwindToMainContent(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {

    }
}

class SegueFromLeft: UIStoryboardSegue
{
    override func perform()
    {
        print("SegueFromLeft called")
        let src = self.source
        let dst = self.destination

        src.view.superview?.insertSubview(dst.view, aboveSubview: src.view)
        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: src.view.frame.size.width, y: 0)

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                       delay: 0.0,
                       options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut,
                       animations: {
                        dst.view.transform = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 0, y: 0)
        },
                       completion: { finished in
                        src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil)
        }
        )
    }
}

class DetailCountryViewController: UIViewController {
    var titleVar = ""

    @IBAction func swipeBack(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segueCountryDetailToMain", sender: self)
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

It crashes in the perform() function in SegueLeft on line

```
completion: { finished in
        src.present(dst, animated: false, completion: nil) }
```

I can't seem to find the error. When it crashes, the src variable is set to DetailCountryViewController and dst is set to ViewController. Where's the error?

**Update 1**
So, I 'fixed' this by changing the above line where the crash occurs to

```
completion: nil
```

Therefore, nothing gets called when ViewController was successfully shown as far as I understood from the documentation. However, when I now go back to DetailCountryViewController again, it crashes again. This time, because DetailCountryViewController is already presented in ViewController and I'm trying to present it again (of course).
Therefore I now know, that the completion handler src.present I chose might not be correct or I should use something else. But what? Do I have to dismiss any controllers anywhere, or...?